# "Your command line PHP installation is too old"

Tags: drush

When trying to run Drush on my shared hosting account I get this error:

> Your command line PHP installation is too old. Drush requires at least PHP 5.3.0.
>   To suppress this check, set the environment variable DRUSH_NO_MIN_PHP=1

When I type `php --version`, it tells me that I am running PHP 5.2.6.

The .bashrc file has the following lines

```
export COLUMNS
alias drush='/usr/bin/php ~/public_html/drush/drush.php'
alias php='/usr/bin/php'
```

How I can fix this?

Comment: You need to upgrade php?

Comment: does http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/44967/drush-fails-to-detect-php-version-correctly help?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I have looked at that thread already but the problem I'm having is I don't know the path to newer versions of php. So I'm not sure how to use that export line. Is this something my host provider would have to tell me?

Comment: *"I don't know the path to newer versions of php."* - ask your sysadmin? We can't know that path. Your sysadmin should assist you with that. Unless ot's a really really cheap hosting, then ask on Super User how to find it without help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem and I was able to specify what version of PHP Drush will use by adding the following to my .bash_profile file:

```
export DRUSH_PHP=/usr/local/php53/bin/php
```

That got mine working.  I had tried a more general approach where I specified PHP 5.3 for my command line generally, but this didn't work.  Specifically targeting Drush is what it took for me.

Comment: if it is php 7 add `/usr/local/php5-7.0.14-20170114-204712/bin/php` or do `ls /usr/local/` and find which php is installed and runing  on  your system. Then add `export /usr/local/PHP_your_version/bin/php`